# $L_p$ and measure convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider the Lebesgue measure. I'm asked to study the $L_p$ and measure convergence of the following functions:

1. $f_n(x)=\mathcal{X}_{[n+3,n+4]}(x)$ in $(0,\infty)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$
2. $g_n(x)=n^3\mathcal{X}_{[0,\frac{1}{log(n+2)}]}(x)$ in $[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

---

1. Since $f_n(x)\longrightarrow 0$ a.e. (as $n\longrightarrow\infty$), we have to check: $$\int_{(0,\infty)} |f_n-0|^p dm=m([n+3,n+4])=1 $$ Therefore, $f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ in $L_p$.
2. Since $g_n(x)\longrightarrow 0$ a.e. (as $n\longrightarrow\infty$),now we have to compute: $$\int_{(0,\infty)} |g_n-0|^p dm=n^{3p}m([0,\frac{1}{log(n+2)}])=\frac{n^{3p}}{log(n+2)}\longrightarrow\infty\;\text{as}\;n\longrightarrow\infty $$
   since $log(n)<<n^{3p}$.

Therefore, $g_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ in $L_p$.

---

But I don't know how to study the convergence in measure. Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: If $ε<1$ then $ \{x : |f_n(x) |> ε \} =[n+3,n+4]$ and so $\mu ( \{x : |f_n(x) |> ε \} ) =1 \not \to 0$. For 2., in a finite measure space a.e. convergence implies convergence in measure.

Comment: Thanks mate!!!!